# AutoMapper custom async resolver

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have DB entity of authors that their data has foreign key as data.

Author DB Entity:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "type": "author",
   "name": "Author1",
   "books": [1, 5, 8]
}
```

I want to restore from my API `AuthorResponse` which is similar, but different. The `AuthorResponse` should return the books entities instead of the IDs.

I created this mapper:

```
this.CreateMap<AuthorEntity, AuthorResponse>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Books, opt => opt.MapFrom<BooksResolver, int[]>(s => s.Books));
```

And the `BooksResolver`:

```
    public class BooksResolver : IMemberValueResolver<AuthorEntity, AuthorResponse, int[], Book[]>
    {
        public Book[] Resolve(AuthorEntity source, AuthorResponse destination, int[] sourceMember, Book[] destMember, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var tasks = sourceMember.Select(id => GetBookFromDbAsync(id));
            return await Task.WhenAll<Book>(tasks); // CAN'T USE AWAIT HERE
        }
    }
```

But `IMemberValueResolver` does not support `async/await`. I can convert this async to sync method, but I don't think it is a good approach.

How can I use AutoMapper for this scenario?

Comment: Don't. Just move that code outside AM. That's not mapping code, that's the logic of your app. AM is intended to map objects to objects. Unless `ProjectTo` fits.

Comment: I see. I just wanted to do that here, since I have several places that I need to map Book id to Book entity in the system... So I wanted to re-use this `BookResolver` everywhere...

Comment: You can do that the old fashioned way, by writing a function :)